# Send and recieve using channel in same function

Tags: go

How can I make a channel 2-way (I don't know if this is right term) in the same function. If I have the following code, then:

```
func server (a <-chan string) {
    data:= <-a
    // now is there a way I can send data through the same channel
    // data <- "yet another string"
}
```

Is there anyother way of implementing this ? Appreciate any help.

Comment: In your example, you have a directional channel (note the arrow in the param), so two way communication isn't possible with this sample code.

Comment: To make it a two ways channel just remove the arrow (a chan string) instead of (a <-chan string)

Comment: @william.taylor.09 In this case, we need to know the size of growth in that channel. In my case, I don't know how much can it expand

Comment: The channel does not change it's size dynamically. You can allocate a buffered channel, meaning it can hold a given amount of items before senders block but by default the channel only allows for one item at a time.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean by size of growth. What is your use case?

Comment: A channel blocks by default, if you specify a size it will buffer up to x elements before blocking. If you don't specify a size you'll have to have atleast one producer and one consumer otherwise the program will enter deadlock mode

Comment: I am trying to be able to write as well as read into the same channel because I have a recursive architecture. It might not be obvious at this abstract description. But what I wanted is (a chan string) instead of (a <-chan string). This does for me!

Comment: By the way, for it to be a two ways channels it has to be created as such. If it is created as read only channel you won't be able to change it to read/write channel.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Warrior:

In the code referred above, the directional pointer with channel restricts the function to do any other activity on that channel instead of the one that is allowed. So, making it:

```
func server (a chan string) {
```

instead of

```
func server (a <-chan string) {
```

will allow the function to send as well as receive data through the same channel.